# Automator - Cyrillic symbols and file writing

Tags: automator, javascript, javascript-automation

I was quite surprised the fact that Apple Automator can make backups for my notes. So I wrote a small script for that. But there are two unsolved issues.

1. In for each files are creating but there are empty
2. The Cyrillic in files is writing like ?????
3. Is it possible somehow to get folder name to structure it with files like in Apple Note (Optional)

Could you please help me with this?

```
var app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true
 
function writeTextToFile(text, file, overwriteExistingContent) {
    try {
        var fileString = file.toString()
        var openedFile = app.openForAccess(Path(fileString), { writePermission: true })
 
        if (overwriteExistingContent) {
            app.setEof(openedFile, { to: 0 })
        }
 
        app.write(text, { to: openedFile, startingAt: app.getEof(openedFile) })
 
        app.closeAccess(openedFile)

        return true
    }
    catch(error) {
        try {
            app.closeAccess(file)
        }
        catch(error) {
            console.log(`Couldn't close file: ${error}`)
        }
 
        return false
    }
}

var notesApp = Application('Notes');
notesApp.includeStandardAdditions = true;
var notes = notesApp.notes;

for(var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
  try {
    var desktopString = app.pathTo("desktop").toString()
    var file = `${desktopString}/copy/${notes[i].name()}.txt`
    var text = notes[i].body();

    writeTextToFile(text, file, true)
  }
  catch(error) {
    var desktopString = app.pathTo("desktop").toString()
    var file = `${desktopString}/ERROR.log`
    writeTextToFile(error.message, file, true)
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the problem with Cyrillics is due to a Unicode encoding problem, but without proper examples it's hard to say more. Can you show a hex dump of a few bytes? See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Answer (score 1):

This is a text-encoding issue, which is solved by specifying how the `write` function should treat the data being written.  You want to declare an `as` property of the second argument, and assign it the value of `"utf8"`.  Therefore, change this line:

```
app.write(text, { to: openedFile, startingAt: app.getEof(openedFile) })
```

to this:

```
app.write(text, { to: openedFile, startingAt: app.getEof(openedFile),
                  as: "utf8" });
```

When reading in from the file, make sure it also gets read in as `"utf8"`.

---

**Some JS notes:**

- The line `notesApp.includeStandardAdditions = true;` isn't doing anything, so you can remove this.
- Terminate your lines with semicolons, which you've done with three of them, but neglected the rest.
- All occurrences of `var` that appear *inside* a function can (and should) be changed to `let`.  This limits the scope of the variable to the block in which the variable is declared, whereas `var` creates a globally-scoped variable, which is almost never advisable.
- All occurrences of `var` that appear *outside* a function can be changed to `const`, since they're constants, which won't have their values changed at any point.